# Converting simple ggplot2 code to use data.table

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

My old code looked like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
gp<-ggplot(NULL,aes(x=Income))
gp<-gp+geom_density(data=dat$Male,color="blue")
gp<-gp+geom_density(data=dat$Female,color="green")
gp<-gp+geom_density(data=dat$Alien,color="red")
plot(gp) #Works
```

Now I have started using the excellent data.table library (instead of data.frame):

```
library(data.table)
cols<-c("blue","green","red")
gp<-ggplot(NULL,aes(x=Income))
dat[, list(gp+geom_density(data=.SD, color=cols[.GRP])), by=Gender]
#I even tried
dat[, list(gp<-gp+geom_density(data=.SD, color=cols[.GRP])), by=Gender]
plot(gp) #Error: No layers in plot
```

I am not exactly sure what is wrong, but it seems that the code I run inside *J()* is not being recognised in the outer scope.

How can I achieve this in an data.table idiomatic way?

Comment: I don't think it will work like that. Remember that a data.table **is** a data.frame and use your old code.

Comment: @Roland, yes ofcourse I can still use my old code. But it would sort of defeat the purpose of using data.table. Afterall, I want to exploit the group by ability of datatable (i.e. dt[,,by=something]) rather than using split()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ggplot2` should be used with long format data.tables in the same way as with long format data.frames:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)

dat <- rbind(data.table(gender="male",value=rnorm(1e4)),
             data.table(gender="female",value=rnorm(1e4,2,1))
             )

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=value,color=gender)) + geom_density()
print(p1)
```

Don't feed wide format data.frames (or data.tables) to ggplot2.

Plotting will be quite slow if you have many groups, but due to the internal magic of `ggplot2` that's nothing `data.table` can really help with (until Hadley implements it somehow). You can try to calulate the densities outside `ggplot2`, but that will only help you so far:

```
set.seed(42)
dat2 <- data.table(gender=as.factor(1:5000),value=rnorm(1e7))
plotdat <- dat2[,list(x_den=density(value)$x,y_den=density(value)$y),by=gender]
p2 <- ggplot(plotdat,aes(x=x_den,y=y_den,color=gender)) + geom_line()
print(p2) #this needs some CPU time
```

Of course, if you have many groups you probably do the wrong kind of plot.